# Unreasonably slow SSH tunnel - but just in the opposite direction

Tags: ssh, rsync, remote-access, ssh-tunnel, slow-connection

While setting up `rsync` to a remote computer, I realized that syncing from my laptop the remote was fast, but the opposite was slow.
After some debugging and `iperf3`, I figured that this only happens under SSH tunnels, as shown by iperf: I've opened port 7500 so that I can run iperf3 with or without SSH in the middle:

**with SSH tunnel from remote port 7500 to local port 9901**

```
enrico@debian-asus1215b:~$ iperf3 -R -c localhost -p 9901
Connecting to host localhost, port 9901
Reverse mode, remote host localhost is sending
[  5] local ::1 port 52818 connected to ::1 port 9901
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  32.0 KBytes   262 Kbits/sec                  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  32.0 KBytes   262 Kbits/sec                  
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  32.0 KBytes   262 Kbits/sec                  
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  32.0 KBytes   262 Kbits/sec                  
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  32.0 KBytes   262 Kbits/sec                  
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  32.0 KBytes   262 Kbits/sec                  
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  32.0 KBytes   262 Kbits/sec                  
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  32.0 KBytes   262 Kbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.06  sec  9.75 MBytes  8.13 Mbits/sec    1             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   256 KBytes   210 Kbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

**Using port 7500 directly**

```
enrico@debian-asus1215b:~$ iperf3 -R -c HOST -p 7500
Connecting to host HOST, port 7500
Reverse mode, remote host HOST is sending
[  5] local 192.168.0.144 port 42074 connected to XXXX port 7500
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.22 MBytes  10.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.52 MBytes  12.7 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  1.39 MBytes  11.6 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.38 MBytes  11.6 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  1.38 MBytes  11.6 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  1.38 MBytes  11.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.39 MBytes  11.6 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  1.37 MBytes  11.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.31 MBytes  11.0 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  1.45 MBytes  12.2 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.02  sec  14.3 MBytes  12.0 Mbits/sec   10             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  13.8 MBytes  11.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Sending speed is unaffected:

**with SSH**

```
enrico@debian-asus1215b:~$ iperf3  -c HOST -p 9901
^C- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
iperf3: interrupt - the client has terminated
enrico@debian-asus1215b:~$ iperf3  -c localhost -p 9901
Connecting to host localhost, port 9901
[  5] local ::1 port 59482 connected to ::1 port 9901
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  12.5 MBytes   105 Mbits/sec    2    639 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  3.75 MBytes  31.4 Mbits/sec    2    639 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  5.00 MBytes  42.0 Mbits/sec    2    639 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec    1    639 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  5.00 MBytes  41.9 Mbits/sec    0    639 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec    0    639 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  3.75 MBytes  31.4 Mbits/sec    0    639 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  3.75 MBytes  31.5 Mbits/sec    1    639 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec    0    639 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  3.75 MBytes  31.5 Mbits/sec    0    639 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  45.0 MBytes  37.7 Mbits/sec    8             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.09  sec  36.6 MBytes  30.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

**without SSH**

```
enrico@debian-asus1215b:~$ iperf3  -c HOST -p 7500
Connecting to host HOST, port 7500
[  5] local 192.168.0.144 port 47376 connected to XXXX port 7500
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  5.82 MBytes  48.8 Mbits/sec    0    318 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  4.45 MBytes  37.3 Mbits/sec    0    366 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  4.08 MBytes  34.2 Mbits/sec    0    397 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  4.26 MBytes  35.8 Mbits/sec    0    439 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  4.45 MBytes  37.3 Mbits/sec    0    439 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  5.44 MBytes  45.6 Mbits/sec    0    439 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  4.57 MBytes  38.4 Mbits/sec    0    439 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  3.58 MBytes  30.1 Mbits/sec    0    439 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  4.51 MBytes  37.8 Mbits/sec    0    439 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  4.51 MBytes  37.8 Mbits/sec    0    439 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  45.7 MBytes  38.3 Mbits/sec    0             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.03  sec  43.8 MBytes  36.7 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

I tested scenario with a VPS I own, and it has no problem in both cases, which leads me to thinking of a sshd problem on my remote pc.

The remote pc sits behind a home router. `mtr` gives the following report:

```
Start: 2024-03-05T13:43:54+0100
HOST: debian-asus1215b      Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- _gateway               0.0%    10    5.6   3.0   1.8   5.6   1.5
  2.|-- 192.168.1.1            0.0%    10    4.6   3.5   2.0   5.5   1.4
  3.|-- 151.7.195.10           0.0%    10    6.7   8.2   4.6  18.6   4.7
  4.|-- 151.7.12.154           0.0%    10    4.9   6.0   4.6  11.1   2.0
  5.|-- 151.6.6.130            0.0%    10   10.8   9.6   8.1  11.0   1.1
  6.|-- 151.6.7.181            0.0%    10   15.4  11.5   9.3  15.4   2.5
  7.|-- 151.6.0.162            0.0%    10   10.2  49.4   9.7 230.6  82.7
  8.|-- 10.254.20.42           0.0%    10   19.4  16.5  14.7  19.5   1.9
  9.|-- ???                   100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 10.|-- HOST                    0.0%    10   23.5  21.4  19.4  23.5   1.6
```

The current situation is that rsyncing from my remote PC to the VPS and then syncing back from the VPS is faster than trying to directly use rsync from the PC.
Unfortunately, I would like to use X11 Forwarding and waypipe, and they are also affected by this issue, as they are extremely laggy.

I'm out of ideas for how to debug this problem. The sshd_config on the remote pc was barely touched. What's puzzling is that it doesn't seem a network speed problem to me.

Comment: Asymmetric upload/download speeds are a classic feature of consumer El cheapo Internet.

Comment: True, but then why does everything work fine without SSH in the middle? Doesn't look like an asymmetric speed problem to me

Comment: `Doesn't look like an asymmetric speed problem to me` what's the MTU? What is the upload performance of a large binary file to any other server? Any information outside the three foot circle of perception from home networking questions.

Comment: MTU is 1500 on both sides (as reported by ifconfig). File upload from my remote PC to my VPS (just as an example) is in the order of MB/s, so very much higher of the few KiB/s I get when pushing data back in the ssh tunnel.